# controller_action_predispatch event is not firing my observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

This is the first observer I'm writing. I'm testing the observer with the `controller_action_predispatch` that should fire when I load a page as an example. This is the files I created:

**/app/etc/modules/EPS_CustomizationURL.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EPS_CustomizationURL>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </EPS_CustomizationURL>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/EPS/CustomizationURL/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EPS_CustomizationURL>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </EPS_CustomizationURL>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>EPS_CustomizationURL_Model</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- observe the event -->
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <epscustomizationurl>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                    </epscustomizationurl>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/EPS/CustomizationURL/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php 
class EPS_CustomizationURL_Model_Observer {
    public function epsURLCreator($observer) {
        $this->_redirectUrl("http://www.google.com");
    } 
}
?>
```

So, as far as I understand as soon as my page loads or even before it I should be redirected to http://www.google.com. This is the only way I could think of to know if my observer is firing.

What am I missing? Any wrong naming, wrong event or `_redirectUrl` is not working? I'm on Magento 1.9.

**EDIT:**
All the caches are disabled so the cache should not be the problem:

[image]

I also tried just logging something instead of redirect and changing the event to `customer_login`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EPS_CustomizationURL>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </EPS_CustomizationURL>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>EPS_CustomizationURL_Model</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
        </models>
        <events>
            <!-- observe the event -->
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                    </eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my observer:

```
<?php 
class EPS_CustomizationURL_Model_Observer {
    public function epsURLCreator($observer) {
        Mage::log('I just made an Observer!', null, 'system.log', true);
    } 
}
```

But still can't see anything in `/var/log/system.log`

Comment: you should get an error because the method `_redirectUrl` does not exist in your class. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: How is the method called? I cleared cache in Chrome only, what other cache should I clear?

Comment: the contents of folder `var/cache` from your magento instance

Comment: Ok, I just did it, but I still get no error when refreshing my pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating the files and folders through FTP. The permission on the files were right but I forgot to set the right permissions for the folders! As soon as I set the folder permissions to 775 it started working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <!-- observe the event -->
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                 <mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch>
                    <class>customizationurl/observer</class>
                    <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                 <mynamespace_mymodule_controller_action_predispatch>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Try the above code in Your xml

Comment: Will not work, his model alias is `epscustomizationurl` not `customizationurl`.

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <epscustomizationurl>
            <class>EPS_CustomizationURL_Model</class>
        </epscustomizationurl>
    </models>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- observe the event -->
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <epscustomizationurl>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                    </epscustomizationurl>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</global>
```

Observer.php

```
class EPS_CustomizationURL_Model_Observer
{
    public function epsURLCreator($observer)
    {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://www.google.com');
    } 
}
```

Try its global undefined.

Comment: Is not working either, I reload any page and I'm not being redirected :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**/app/etc/modules/Eps_Customizationurl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eps_Customizationurl>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Eps_Customizationurl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Eps/Customizationurl/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eps_Customizationurl>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eps_Customizationurl>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>Eps_Customizationurl_Model</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>Eps_Customizationurl_Helper</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsUrlCreator</method>
                    </Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php 
/* We will redirect to the checkout/cart for exemple */
class Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function epsUrlCreator($observer) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('You have been redirected to the cart !');//if you want to display some message.
        $url = Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart') ? Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'): Mage::getUrl();
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        exit;
    } 
}
?>
```

**/app/code/local/Eps/Customizationurl/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Eps_Customizationurl_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```