# Disable page for not logged in users

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page

How to show 404 for the unlogged user instead of page?
For now, I have: when the user is not logged the page link does not show in the main menu. But when I type the URL (page.com/my_page) I get redirect to my_page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean if user not logged in you want to redirect them to 404 page ?

Comment: @RaviSoni, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I'm new to magento. Correct me if i'm wrong. I have to create custom module for that? And in config.xml I have to define events?

Comment: Yes, you have to define it in config.xml. But what your exact requirement? If user not logged in, you want them to redirect on 404 page. Right? In short, you don't allow the guest user on your website. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have page for example "my_page" and if i go to page.com/my_page i want to redirect to 404 if i'm not logged in.

Comment: It's a cms page?

Comment: no it's not. I want to disable only one page for not logged in users.

Comment: @SebastianT You can use below added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

> /app/etc/modules/Custom_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Custom/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Custom_Module_Model</class>
            </custommodule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Custom_Module_Helper</class>
            </custommodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <Custom_Module_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>noRoutUrl</method>
                    </Custom_Module_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/Custom/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Custom_Module_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function noRoutUrl($observer) {
        if ((strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'my_page') != false) && (! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()))  {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/no-route');
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

> /app/code/local/Custom/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

class Custom_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

This the step you have to follow by creating all files

Comment: Thank You very much, it works perfect! Could you tell me, where can i find informations about "controller_action_predispatch" and others events. Where to find name of event which i want to use?

Comment: Here is the link for all events:  https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code:

```
<?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'my_page') != false && ! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())  {

            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/no-route');

        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, could you explain please where to paste this code?

Comment: @SebastianT, If You know how to use event observer in Magento then follow this link:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181579/controller-action-predispatch-event-is-not-firing-my-observer  and under the Observer.php add you r logic. which i have provided you.